# MySQL: How many table rows are scanned in JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join, optimization

If I have three tables each having 1000 rows with number from 1 to 1000, then how many comparisons does MySQL during the following `JOIN`s queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1 t1 
JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.id_1 = t2.id_2
JOIN table_3 t3 ON t2.id_2 = t3.id_3;
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1 t1 
JOIN table_2 t2 
JOIN table_3 t3
WHERE t1.id_1 = t2.id_2 AND t2.id_2 = t3.id_3;
```

Note that there are no indexes on any of the tables. Is there a difference between the two queries? I'm thinking that in second query, it is written with the intention such that MySQL would create a cartesian product of all three tables and then filter out the rows matching the condition(having to scan 1000 X 1000 X 1000 rows) but internally it is translated to first query in which it would scan 1000 X 1000 rows in the first JOIN followed by another 1000 X 1000 rows in the second JOIN. The result should be same(1000 rows with three columns have same number 1 to 1000).

**Which one is it? 1000 X 1000 X 1000 rows OR 1000 X 1000 + 1000 X 1000 rows**

Question arose after reading the following from "Query Optimization" chapter from MySQL by Paul DuBois(4th edition, page 306):

[image]

Comment: With or without indexes the DBMS implements queries using rearrangements from naive nested/logical evaluation order of the given expression to algorithms. And the manual if you google join optimization does a trivial optimization to implement these the same way. If you are going to ask a question like this it has to be after you research the manual & textbooks re the topic or you are just asking us to rewrite them. Also ON vs WHERE optimization is a SO faq. "I'm thinking" is pointless if you are uninformed. [ask] [help] For code questions give relevant parts of a [mre]--including SQL plans.

Comment: If you have a question re that presentation, give context & ask it. Otherwise (and regardless) I hope you will act per my comments. PS Again, even without indexes MySQL can have statistics, constraints, etc etc by which to implement/optimize/plan queries. If you had googled the manual as I suggested you'd also haec seen confirmation that these queries are always treated identically.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: I think the book is talking in theoretical sense...if we have to join three sets each consisting of integers 1 through 1000, there are two ways to find all combinations where elements from all three sets are the same {1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}....One, you can find all possible combinationation (10^9) and then scan all of them to find those specific 1000 combinations(book is suggesting this). Other is, for each of the 1000 items in first set, scan the second set(1000 rows) and the third set(another 1000 rows) for matching element leading 1000 x (1000 + 1000) scans;

Comment: Second is what MySQL "would" do but impossible to say without specific details about table structures, indexes, engines etc.... @philipxy, your answer is wrong, please see above comment...

Comment: @Pepria The book is clearly talking about alternate implementations/algorithms not limited to what MySQL does. Re alternate queries "which would eliminate rows during the JOIN"--MySQL treats them all the same per 8.2.1.1 WHERE Clause Optimization & 8.2.1.7 Nested Join Optimization whatever else it does & if one wants to discuss theoretical evaluations then one must give a particular mapping from SQL expressions to algorithms. Re my "answer is wrong", I guess you mean, my comment is wrong; I think I was trying to say what you're trying to say, but I think both of us wrote unclearly.

Answer (score 0):

Those two queries are treated the same.

For *clarity*, `ON` should state how the tables are related; `WHERE` should filter.

But, for *optimization*, those are equivalent for `JOIN`.

FOr `LEFT JOIN`, it *does* matter where you put the conditions.

As an extra wrinkle to your question,...  If the tables had different numbers of rows, the Optimizer would probably start with the smallest table.

See this to find out how to count the rows:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can understand `id_1`, etc.

It would be foolish to run such code without indexes.

What is the expected output?  Something like this?

```
+---+---+---+
| n | n | n |
+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 |
...
```

Comment: All three tables have the same number of rows. My main question is the number of rows scanned ?

Comment: @oneCoderToRuleThemAll Edit your post to clearly ask the 1 question that is your question.

Comment: @oneCoderToRuleThemAll - I added some stuff to my Answer.  Can you provide a complete test case?  I'll get the numbers for you.